# 3 Divs with different percentage of screen size that scale

Tags: css, html

I am new to divs and need to create a web page that doesn't scroll with a main div that takes up 60% of the screen, a div underneath that that takes up 30% and a footer that takes up 10% with zero padding between each div. It can't scroll and must scale with the browser window. Has anyone done this? I tried doing this and the 2nd div would never position itself correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the (very many) questions about fixed headers and footers. Your question seems to be a variation on this. Short answer: you probably can't do it without scripting the math.

Comment: Between elements you have `margin` not `padding`.

Comment: @isherwood What are you on? That is very easy.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of fixed-height header/footer scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**This should work**](http://jsfiddle.net/TRJK5/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:nth-child(1){
    height:60%;
    background:red;
}
div:nth-child(2){
    height:30%;
    background:yellow;
}
div:nth-child(3){
    height:10%;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's what I am looking for. I'll give it a try.